# How to deal with unescaped single quotes in scrapy?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        if 'BristolQualification' in item:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bristol(BristolCountry, BristolQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BristolCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BristolQualification']])))
        elif 'BathQualification' in item:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bath(BathCountry, BathQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BathCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BathQualification']])))
        self.conn.commit()
    return item

    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

I have this code in my pipelines, it works but it skips around 15% of the results and doesnt extract them to my databse and I believe it's due to unescaped single quotes such as (d'Etudes) in the snippet below.

> Candidates holding a Dipl\xf4me de Technicien Sup\xe9rieur / Sciences Appliqu\xe9es with suitable grades or those with the Dipl\xf4me d'Etudes Universitaires G\xe9n\xe9rales (DEUG) with good grades in suitable subjects will be considered for appropriate undergraduate courses.

Can anyone think how to deal with them?

Comment: Did you tried with `MySQLdb.escape_string()` ? Check this http://nullege.com/codes/search/MySQLdb.escape_string

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide an example please?

Comment: e.g try:  `alification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(( MySQLdb.escape_string(item['BathCountry']), MySQLdb.escape_string("".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BathQualification']]))`